# How much damage can I do by installing a module in the wrong place with npm?

Tags: node.js, npm

I've got an iOS app, using google cloud functions and want to install the Request module/package https://www.npmjs.com/package/request in the node_modules folder.

My folder structure is:

```
- Desktop
      - myApp
           - firebase
                  - functions
                        - node_modules
```

I was reading up on npm about npm install and there was some stuff about installing locally, globally and some other things I didn't quite get.

Is there a standard way to install packages with npm?

And if I wanted to install "Request" in the terminal do i "cd" to the node_modules folder and npm install from there or is it from within the functions folder?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same directory where you have the node_module directory (i.e. in your functions directory) you should also have package.json file. If you are in that directory and you run `npm install request --save` then you will install the module and put it in the dependencies in package.json file. That is what installing locally means. For more info see:

- https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/dependencies

(Cloud functions for Firebase work pretty much the same as Google Cloud Functions)

### Update

The `--save` is the default behavior of `npm install` since v5.0 so you don't need to use the `--save` flag since the saving is done automatically (there is `--no-save` to prevent saving).

See the release notes for more info:

- https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v5.0.0